Как получить bbox тайла?
Использую postgis и RemoteObjectManager для получение геообъектов по тайлам(x,y,zoom).
Проблема в том, что bbox тайла на карте не совпадает с postgis. Если взять bbox в postgis ST_Transform(st_tileenvelope(${z}, ${x}, ${y}), 4326) - тайлы постоянно сдвинуты вверх.
Пробовал код преобразования тайла в bbox - тоже сдвинуты.
function tileXToLng(x, zoom) {
    return (x / Math.pow(2, zoom) * 360 - 180);
}

function tileYToLat(y, zoom) {
    const n = Math.PI - 2 * Math.PI * y / Math.pow(2, zoom);
    return (180 / Math.PI * Math.atan(0.5 * (Math.exp(n) - Math.exp(-n))));
}

Как исправить в postgis(может трансформ какой нужен) или как поправить код под проекцию Яндекс.Карт?

Скорее всего у вас не правильный перевод из EPSG:3857 в EPSG:4326 попробуйте реализовать вот этот код

Вот ещё как вариант
